# Nunit Testing - OneTimeSetUp: Only supported on Windows 10

Tags: azure-devops, nunit, windows-server-2016, vstest

I am running tests in Azure DevOps using an interactive agent on a local machine running Windows Server 2016.

When running VsTest in Azure I am receive the following error:

> OneTimeSetUp: Only supported on Windows 10.

Changing the OS to windows 10 is not an option. Is there any way to work around this problem ?

I am using NUnit Adapter 4.0.0.0 , VsTest 2.170.1 ,  TestPlatformVersion: 16.11.0

```cs
[OneTimeSetUp]
public void SetUpTest() 
{
    driver = Driver.DriverInstance;
    wait = Driver.WaitInstance;
    var url = "lastminute.co.il";
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
}
```

Comment: This could be because the agent isn't started in Interactive mode or because of what's happening in your `OneTimeSetUp()`. Please see [Azure Pipelines agents - Interactive vs. service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#interactive-or-service). Could you post some (relevant) code? Please refer to [example].

Comment: Hi thank you for replaying! the agent is running in interactive mode.

Comment: Are you sure none of your tests of fixtures have the NUnit `PlatformAttribute` specifying that the test only works on Windows 10? The message is very much like what you might see with such an attribute on a test fixture.

Comment: Yes I did had some PlatformAttribute  indicting os version windows 10. I removed them and now the problem is solved Thank you @Charlie!